# Calling a method in specific time of everyday

Tags: android, timer, task, schedule

Hi I have a full screen app;
First
I want eg. 6pm hide all objects then show them again in a specific time, everyday. based on device time.

Second, I want to send status and GPS info in every 15 minute, I have a method for it but how can I call it every 15 minute?

Comment: try to use the alarmmanager

Comment: just google for alarmmanager, you will find tons of examples there

Answer (score 1):

To schedule a recurring task, you can use a Timer with a TimerTask.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Eg. For your 2nd question, to do something every 15 minutes starting from now:

```
long INTERVAL_MSEC = 900000;
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        sendStatusAndGPS();
    }
}
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, INTERVAL_MSEC);
```

For your first question, you can pass instead the start time as the second parameter to timer.scheduleAtFixedRate.

You can also use a Handler with the postAtTime method.

Comment: I found timertask example with just timer, I want it for clock time.
eg. at 6pm get visible false, and 9am visible true on every day..

Answer (score 0):

as nitegazer2003 said you can use:

public void schedule (TimerTask task, Date when, long period);

but if you want to start repeated timer for specific hour of day you must set when variable,
for example if you want timer that repeat every day at 6 you can do something like this:

```
// get today date
    Date curent_time= new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(curent_time);
    int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int sec = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    long when = (6 * 3600)
    - ( (hour*3600) + (min *60) + sec);
// interval should be based on miliseconds so
    long interval = 24*60*60*1000;
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new testtimertask(), when, interval);
```

but you need to consider curent_time is not past your start time, if so you should use another formula to calculate when to start the timer.

Answer (score 0):

so you need a scheduling option that wakes your application so you should use `AlarmManager` for doing this u should take a look at [this link on developers site](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms)

the idea is that you create a service that gets called every 30 minutes and you will write your GPS location code inside that service.

this is my code for it **inside the LocationService.Class**

```
public class LocationService extends Service
{

    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener
    {
        Location mLastLocation;

        public LocationListener(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location currentLocation)
        {
            sendAllLocationsToServer();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
        }
    }

    private void sendAllLocationsToServer() {
        //send locations to server
    }

    LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return START_STICKY;
        }
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            initializeLocationManager();
            try {
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                        mLocationListeners[1]);
            } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
            }
            try {
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                        mLocationListeners[0]);
            } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            /*try {
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                        mLocationListeners[1]);
            } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
            }*/
            try {
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                        mLocationListeners[0]);
            } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
            }
            try {
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                        mLocationListeners[1]);
            } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void cancelService(){
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationService.class);
        alarmIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                alarmIntent, 0);
        alarmMgr.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        //TODO should implement an stop point for this service
        initializeLocationManager();
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[1]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[0]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
                try {
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
                }
            }
        }
        stopSelf();
    }

    private void initializeLocationManager() {
        Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }
}
```

you can cancel this service by calling cancel() method but your `requestCode` should be the same as when you create your `PendingIntent`

both of your questions is answered in the link provided.